# No PWM Output On STM32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

No PWM output for a timer on a stm32f4discovery board whatsoever. Straight line on oscilloscope.

Note: code was generated in Stm32cubeide except the "user code" part

**Main Function**

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

**Initialization of TIM2**

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void) 
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 100;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}
```

I've also tried instead of `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start`, `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT`,and `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set Pulse value greater than zero and less than your period value; it is duty of your PWM. Zero duty generates zero out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines that I've written below here;

```c
    ...
    uint16_t pwm_val; //Define the value to determine duty cycle - pwm_val = <some value>
    while (1)
    {
    /* This is going to start pwm out */
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, pwm_val);
    }
    ...
```